# How to Synchronise two database using Pentaho?

Tags: database, python-3.x, postgresql, pentaho, pentaho-data-integration

I'm using **Pentaho** service to import all tables and data from a SQL database to a pgSQL database. I'm using the '**sort row**' transformation for this.

Now what I need is to **sync the two databases** frequently. (ie, changes occurred in SQL db needs to reflects on pgSQL db)

How can I do this or **which transformation do I need to use**?

Answer (score 0):

you can create one job which executes every 2 minutes or 5 minutes depending on your new data frequency in sql db and takes the new data and dumps into pgsql db. there are various way to do it.

one of such is check for look-up,explore how it works and you will get idea.